# Apple photopicker upload taken picture with php to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, camera

i have downloaded the sample code for the photopicker from Apple here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

I have modified the section of the code that represent the result of the picture taken (the snap shot button) in the MyViewController.m :

```
// as a delegate we are being told a picture was taken
- (void)didTakePicture:(UIImage *)picture
{
    [self.capturedImages addObject:picture];
}
```

Then to use a code similar as this one to push it out to my web server :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(**_capturedImages.images**, 90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

The problem that I have is I keep having messages saying that the file cannot be uploaded or the code just crash.

I think is is just a matter of accessing correctly the resulting image and push it correctly.

Because I do not know how to extract the image from this from MyViewController.m:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) **NSMutableArray** *capturedImages;
```

The PHP Code for upload.php is :

```
<?php

    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadFile = $file;
    $randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
    $newName = $randomNumber . $uploadFile;

    echo $file;

    echo $uploadFile;

    echo $randomNumber;

    echo $newName;

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
    }

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) {
        exit("Your file is too large."); 
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) 
    {
            $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
            $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was 
            $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
            $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');

            echo "http://localhost/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
    }

?>
```

Thanks

Regis

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice example for uploading using AFNetworking
http://www.6foot3foot.com/developer-journal/afnetworking-php